# Unknown callstack Android

Tags: android

My android native application[5.0] crashes randomly but frequently.

I don't have any proper info from the call stack.

02-20 06:13:09.367  3085  3085 I DEBUG   : backtrace:
02-20 06:13:09.367  3085  3085 I DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00010014  
02-20 06:13:09.367  3085  3085 I DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000ab30c

And from the stack also not getting any usable information.
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00010014  
    #01 pc 000ab30c

stack:
         f387a790  df42c3e4
         f387a794  f387af34  [stack:23843]
         f387a798  df42c2e1
         f387a79c  00000000
         f387a7a0  00000000
         f387a7a4  00000000
         f387a7a8  00000000
         f387a7ac  f387a92c  [stack:23843]
         f387a7b0  00000002
         f387a7b4  00000002
         f387a7b8  ffffffff
         f387a7bc  e00d1b71  /data/data/com.sec.android.app.myApp/app_myApp/paks/resources.pak
         f387a7c0  40e59899  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
         f387a7c4  79a6b50b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc-space-gap (deleted)
         f387a7c8  40e5989b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)

So how to proceed further in such scenarios.

Comment: The stack always has usable information.  Please post it.

Comment: Hi @simon Attached stack info.

Comment: Interesting observation which i found was this issue happens when system enters to low memory case i.e Available Mem less <50 MB.